# About the evil of eval: How to clean up

Tags: php, javascript, eval

I'm building a site that will (eventually) be the front-end for a game. I want to be able to dynamically build a list of "powers" that the user is able to purchase. In order to build these lists, I'm using a PHP-based SQL query, then passing it to Javascript for dynamic choices (some powers have prerequisite powers).

1. I know there's a simpler way to do what I'm doing, but I'm not super concerned with that right now (I will be later, but I'm trying to get this functional and *then* clean) (again, I know this is non-optimal).
2. I'm using eval to parse which divs to show, and I want to know how not to.
3. I'm having issues getting my div names built right in the first place.

Here's my code:
Javascript (separate file)

```
function upgradeList(passed)
{
    var PowerArray = [];
    var DetailPowerID = [];
    var EscapedPowerID = [];
    PowerArray.push([]);
    PowerArray = eval(passed);
    var OutputThing="";
    for (i=0;i<PowerArray.length;i++)
    {
        DetailPowerID[i] = 'detail' + PowerArray[i][0];
        EscapedPowerID[i] = "'" + DetailPowerID[i] + "'";
    }
    for (i=0;i<PowerArray.length;i++)
    {
        OutputThing = OutputThing + "<br><a href='#' onClick='showUpgradeDetails(" + DetailPowerID[i] + ")'>" + PowerArray[i][2] + "</a><div class='hidden' id='" +
        DetailPowerID[i] + "'>" + PowerArray[i][3] + "</div>";  }
        document.getElementById("secondUpgrade").innerHTML=OutputThing;
        document.getElementById("secondUpgrade").style.display='block';
    }
}
```

PHP writing HTML and JS:
{$AbleToUpgrade and $UpgradeList are both 2d arrays built from SQL queries)

```
echo "<script name='UpgradeList'>";
settype($UpgradesListSize[$i],"int");
for ($i=0;$i<count($AbleToUpgrade);$i++)
{
    echo "var UpgradeList" . $AbleToUpgrade[$i][0] . " = new Array();";
    for ($j=0;$j<=$UpgradesListSize[$i];$j++)
    {
        echo "UpgradeList" . $AbleToUpgrade[$i][0] . ".push(Array('"
            . $UpgradeList[$i][$j][0] . "', '"
            . $UpgradeList[$i][$j][1] . "', '"
            . $UpgradeList[$i][$j][2] . "', '"
            . $UpgradeList[$i][$j][3] . "', '"
            . $UpgradeList[$i][$j][4] . "'));";
    }
}
echo "</script>";
```

... and, later...

```
echo "<div id='SpendUpgrade'>
    Select power to upgrade:
    <ul>";
    for ($i=0;$i<count($AbleToUpgrade);$i++)
    {
        echo "<li><a href='#' name='UpgradeList" . $AbleToUpgrade[$i][0] . "' onClick='upgradeList(this.name)'>" . $AbleToUpgrade[$i][1] . " - " . $AbleToUpgrade[$i][2] . "</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</select>
    <div id='secondUpgrade' class='hidden'>

    </div>
    <div id='thirdUpgrade' class='hidden'>

    </div>
</div>";
```

When I load the page, I wind up with generated text like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showUpgradeDetails(detail21)">Real Armor</a>
```

and the corresponding div:

```
<div class="hidden" id="detail21" style="display: none;">Your armor only works in the Waking</div>
```

In order to get the div to show `(display:block;)`, I need to call the function like so:

```
showUpgradeDetails("detail21")
```

but I can't make JS / PHP write the quotes correctly. Help (with any or all of this?) please!

Comment: json_encode-JSON.parse, JSON.stringify-json_decode

Comment: Encoding your data as JSON seems to be a possible solution. Learn more about JSON: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json.

Comment: using JSON.parse() returns all sorts of nasty errors, and I don't know enough about it to resolve them. With beginners knowledge, it looks like my variables aren't formatted as JSON objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution, and it wasn't `JSON.parse()`. 
I changed `PowerArray = eval(passed);` into `PowerArray = window[passed];`.

Because `passed` contains the name of a variable, and is not the variable itself, I couldn't work directly with it. However, because it was a string that held exclusively the name of a globally-defined variable, I could pass it to the `window[]` construct and have it work.